# How come "Lecks" is pluralized the same way as its English counterpart "Leaks"?

Tags: translation

I've just found out when I've sent our machine safety labels for translation that the English word "Leaks" is translated as "Lecks" in German. How come this word is pluralized the same way as an English word?

Comment: "Leck" is originally a Dutch word (Dutch plural "lekken") that was imported into German, see http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GL03101#XGL03101. Many foreign words get the "-s" plural in German. See https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plural#Der_s-Plural

Comment: Why not? Page 8, second bullet: http://www.personal.uni-jena.de/~x1gape/Wort/Wort_Nomen_Pluralform.pdf

Comment: Taken from Low German/Dutch a long time ago, though http://www.dwds.de/?qu=Leck

Comment: Thanks for the answers. My German is rusted and even I know that there are irregularities in plural forms I was expecting this word to be regularly pluralized. If you post one of your answers I can select it as the correct answer.

Comment: Wrack/Wracks and Dock/Docks and Hotel/Hotels is the same *irregularity*. So it probably even isn't something irregular ;)

Comment: @what I am not happy with the Wikipedia article - With the chosen examples, it creates the impression as if the -s Plural would exclusively be used with English loanwords and abbreviations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding a plural-s is one of the wide variety of possible plural forms in German. It is a valid form and does not have much of a connection to the English plural-s (although there might be common roots).

Some more examples of substantives that use the "s"-plural form:

- Wrack / Wracks
- Dock / Docks
- Deck / Decks

Those words seem to have a common root in Low German/Dutch with their English counterparts and have a marine background.

- Hotel / Hotels
- Reck / Recks (also: Recke)
- Auto / Autos
- Hobby / Hobbys
- Opa / Opas
- Mutti / Muttis
- Junge / Jungs (also: Jungen)
- Foto / Fotos
- Sofa / Sofas
- and many more...

Some of those (probably) have a common root with their English counterpart, some don't.